# How to requestFocusInWindow after JOptionPane?

Tags: java, swing, focus, jtextfield, joptionpane

I have the following code:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Wrong format!", "Wrong format!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

myJTextField.requestFocusInWindow();
```

The JTextField does not get focus after execution of JOptionPane, how do I fix this in a nice and clean way? My JTextField is on a JTabbedPane.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I would do that Sir but the application I am working on is very complex and honestly I wouldn't know where to start.

Answer (score 3):

this isn't easy job move `Focus` betweens two `Top-Level Containers`, because Focus came from native OS and is asynchronous,

you have to delay this event to the `invokeLater()`, if without success then you have to look for [Dialog Focus](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/03/14/dialog-focus/) by `@camickr`

Comment: I have noticed that the problem I am having is somehow browser related. Works fine in IE, but not in Firefox.

Comment: *"wouldn't know where to start."*  Start with an applet, a text field and an option pane.  If that works in IE, but not FF, that is the SSCCE.

Answer (score 0):

`showMessageDialog` blocks the EDT until you have confirmed the dialog. So the line of code you have setting the focus won't run until after the dialog is gone.